# How to do unit testing for json schema validation in C# Web API

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have API endpoint where I am validating input json against the JSON schema I have in table from DB. Its working fine. Now I need to add unit test for it. I am using xunit for unit testing. I am stuck on how that schema validation will work in unit testing as I dont know how to generate dummy schema in xUnit and then compare it. Below is the code from my API.

```
var schemadefination= JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(schemafromDB);
var schema = schemadefination.Result;
JToken json = JToken.Parse(inputfromAPI);
var errors = schema.Validate(json);

if (errors.Count > 0)
{
return BadRequest()
}
```

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to test. From my perspective you actually want to test, that your schema is well defined, whereas "generating a dummy-schema" to validate that would be pretty contradictory, wouldn't it? Testing the validation-function of Newtonsoft on the other hand is pretty pointless, as this is already done by the package-owners. So there's not much here to worry about despite said JSON-schemafile itself

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I must have to add unit test case for this scenario. I am using NJsonSchema not Newtonsoft.

Comment: then ask your boss what exactly you should test here. From my persptive only the JSON-schema itself needs to be tested, whereas faking it would be completely contradictory.

Comment: In other words: `FromJsonAsync` has already been tested, as well as `JToken.Parse` and `schema.Validate`. There's no need to provide tests for these functions again. The only thing that is under your own control and thus can be tested is the schema-file

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain if I want to schema file, is there way to do it in unit testing.

Comment: I doubt you will get a single test for an entire schema. You will need a testcase for every scenario where validation should fail, which is impossible for us to know.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I just want to generate a fake json schema and test it against some fake input value.

Comment: but where's the point in doing so? Either fake your data to check if your schema is correct, or fake your schema to check that your data is correct. However doing both is pretty pointless.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I have no option but to do it. I can fake my data but stuck on how to create fake schema.